# Return subsetted data in R function

Tags: r, function, subset

I am trying to write a simple function to summarize some data.
I constructed a function with 4 arguments, to subset the main table based on some categories.
The problem is that when I run the function with arguments that subset my data (unitate), I don't see printed the summary statistics or subset tables. Basically, the code only works up to the line: *return(tabel_masive_global)*.

Here is the code. Thanks.

```
> #Functie tabel avansat
fct_tab_av <- function(baza, unitate){
  #Incarcare pachete necesare
  library(plyr)
  library(xlsx)

  #Sumarizarea pe toti peretiii
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("#Sumarizare pentru toti peretii")
  print(summary(baza))

  #Tabel statistic global pe masive
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("#Tabel statistic global pe masive")
  tabel_masive_global <- ddply(baza,~Masiv, summarise, Nr_Pereti=length(Masiv),S_tot = sum(Suprafata), S_med=mean(Suprafata), H_med = mean(Inaltimea), Pa_med=mean(Panta), Alt_med=mean(Altitudinea), SD_Suprafata=sd(Suprafata), SD_Inaltimea=sd(Inaltimea), SD_Panta=sd(Panta), SD_Altitudinea=sd(Altitudinea))
  return(tabel_masive_global)

  #Subset pe unitate
  subs_unitate <- subset(baza, Unitate=="unitate")
  return(subs_unitate)
  #Sumarizare pe unitate
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("#Sumarizare pe unitate")
  print(summary(subs_unitate))

  #Tabel statistic pe unitate in functie de litologie
  print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("Tabel statistic pe unitate in functie de litologie")
  tabel_unitate <- ddply(subs_unitate, ~Litologia_N, summarise, Nr_Pereti=length(Masiv), Proc_Pereti=((Nr_Pereti*100)/(nrow(x))), S_tot = sum(Suprafata), S_med=mean(Suprafata), H_med = mean(Inaltimea), Pa_med=mean(Panta), Alt_med=mean(Altitudinea), SD_Suprafata=sd(Suprafata), SD_Inaltimea=sd(Inaltimea), SD_Panta=sd(Panta), SD_Altitudinea=sd(Altitudinea))
  return(tabel_unitate)
  }
```

Comment: once you hit a return, the function finishes. Do something like return(a,b,c,d) at the very end.

Comment: @jeremycg you should write that as an answer

Comment: You can only return one "thing" from a function. If you want to return multiple elements, you can put them in a list `return(list(a,b,c,d))` at the *end* of your function.

Answer (score 0):

`return()` ends a function - any time you hit a return, the function will give you the output, and exit. For your function, remove all the returns, and put at the very end:

```
return(list(tabel_masive_global, subs_unitate, tabel_unitate))
```

I would also not call `library()` inside a function - every time you call the function, you reload the libraries, which will slow it down considerably.

Edit: Here is an example of how return works, using comments (#) to explain:

```
mycoolfunction <- function(x,y,z){
     print(x) #prints out the x value
     cat(y) #another way of printing
     return(list(y,z)) #returns a list of y and z as an object! function is now exited
     print(x) #not done
     print(y) #not done
}
```

Now let's see what we get:

```
mycoolfunction(1,2,3)
```

You should get:

```
[1] 1 
2[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Which has `[1] 1` we get from printing 1, `2` we got from cat on 2 - we don't get the line designator(`[1]`) or a newline from cat, and the list of y and z.
We don't reprint x or y as the function has already returned.

Now lets try with assignment:

```
x=mycoolfunction(1,2,3)
[1] 1
2
```

This time we only print and cat.
But if we ask what x is, it's our list of y and z:

```
x

[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: Still doesn't print the subsetted data. Do I need to write the summarries after the return line?

Comment: Once the function hits a return, it's done, so put the summaries above. If you just want to print to the console change the returns to print, if you want to be able to use them in another way, return is what you want.

Comment: I used return, as you suggested, but it still doesn't prints the subsetted data frames or summaries for subsetted data.